# C++ sharing array elements across modules with const-ness for few fields only

Tags: c++, arrays

This is sort of a design doubt . 
Scenario: I have an array which contain some integer elements . This array is populated by 1 module (.so) in my code base say X. It is then shared to another module say Y (.so) . At run time X module identifies that module Y would need to work on few fields of the array and modify it and that was the reason X shared the array to Y . ( Both these so are consumed into one binary .) 
Once Y returns  the module X prints the array .

Problem : How can I enforce programatically that module Y does not modify any other array index other than the one identified by X . SInce the whole array is passed between modules i cant make it const as then Y would not be able to change any field . You can say i want to enforce const-ness for few fields identified at run time .

Comment: Some sort of wrapper for writing into the array and some bookkeeping as to which parts of the array can be modified through given wrapper?

Comment: Send an array of pointers to the elements that need modifying.  (Obviously, you still can prevent the consumer from using pointer arithmetic to do naughty things...)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
template <class T> class CProtectedArray {
private:
    T*              m_aItems;
    unsigned int*   m_aMask;
public:
    CProtectedArray(int cElem, bool fInitialProtect) : m_aItems(NULL)  {
        int cbElem = sizeof(T)*cElem;
        int cbMask = sizeof(int)*(cElem+31)/32;
        m_aItems = (T*)malloc(cbElem + cbMask);
        m_aMask = (unsigned int*)(m_aItems + cElem);
        memset(m_aItems, 0, cbElem);
        memset(m_aMask, fInitialProtect ? -1 : 0, cbMask);
    }
    ~CProtectedArray() {
        if (m_aItems)
            free(m_aItems);
    }
    bool IsProtected(int iItem)     { return !!(m_aMask[iItem>>5] & (1<<(iItem&31))); }
    void Protect(int iItem)         { m_aMask[iItem>>5] |= 1<<(iItem&31); }
    void UnProtect(int iItem)       { m_aMask[iItem>>5] &= ~(1<<(iItem&31)); }
    void Set(int iItem, T val) {
        if (!IsProtected(iItem))
            m_aItems[iItem] = val;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CProtectedArray<int> A(100, true);
    bool f = A.IsProtected(30);  // f = true
    A.Set(30, 23);  // nothing happens
    A.UnProtect(30); 
    f = A.IsProtected(30);  // f = false
    A.Set(30, 24); // sets element 30 to 24
    A.Protect(30); 
    f = A.IsProtected(30);  // f = true
    A.Set(30, 25);  // nothing happens
}
```